# Data points in Highstock is not visible

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using [Gantt chart](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) to create a data visualization. My data duration for a process is up-to 1 second so it is not visible properly in this  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/qgacggkm/2/). Is there any way I can display small and large duration processes equally visible in Highstock?

Chart option

```
    chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    renderTo: 'chart',
    events: {
        load: function(e) {
            var max = maxDate;
            var range = (24 * 3600 * 1000) * 7; // one day * 7
            this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(max - range, max);
        }
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Processes Run'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: xAxisStepping,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        month: '%b %e, %Y'
    },
    min: minDate,
    max: maxDate,
    minRange: 1000
}, yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    title: '',
    categories: categories,
    min: minY,
    max: maxY,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
},
navigator: {
    enabled: true
},
series: data,
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var seriesName = this.series.name;
        return seriesName;
    }
}, credits: {
    enabled: false
},
exporting: {
    enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        turboThreshold: 200000,
        maxPointWidth: 50,
        pointWidth: 50
    },
    line: {
        lineWidth: 50,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            //align: 'center',
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            y: -6,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.series.name;
            }
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 50
            }
        }
    },
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        animation: false,
        turboThreshold: 100000000,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let's analise this example: http://jsfiddle.net/k8hg7q3u/ when you set the smallets posibble range on the axis you have intercal like 5 minutes, how physically you would like to print 1second bar? The disproportion between data and your axis ranges are too big.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: If I zoom to the smallest task, at least it should be visible, even clickable.When I try to zoom with navigator in chrome I get errors that it reached negative value, probably the left nav slider moved to the right of right nav slider

Comment: Without modifying the plugin, you can add a 1px stroke in CSS to make all points visible: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/qgacggkm/4/. To make this more flexible, we could add a borderWidth property to the plugin itself, as well as a borderColor for instance. It would make sense that it could inherit the color from the point or the series.

Comment: @SebastianBochan:Thanks, I am also trying an alternative where I can zoom in to tooltip and then have an option to click on the task, but it will require multiple zooms and reset button resets it to last place, instead I need to zoom it to the 1st place where zoom was started. I used `afterSetExtremes` and `selection` event to do this but some how it does not go back to 1st zoomed position. [http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/qgacggkm/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/qgacggkm/5/)

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Also in your solution can you share a snippet where I can add `borderWidth` and `borderColor` so that it will inherit the color from the point or series? Thanks

Comment: In the chart redraw function, you can loop over each point and apply stroke-width and color, by attr() function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/31wzr7pq/

Comment: @SebastianBochan: When I hover on any process it disappears

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/3h4340p0/